# Vim: How to replace multiple instances of string, but only between certain delimiters within that string

Tags: regex, vim

This is a regex question.  In this particular case I'm using Vim to do the work, but I'd be interested in the general answer to the regex portion for other times I'm using other varieties of regex.

Consider the following example where I want to replace some arbitrary text string "ab" with some other text "cd", but only if it occurs between the words START and END:

```
Before:
 ab ab ab START ab ab ab END ab ab ab

I would like this to become:
 ab ab ab START cd cd cd END ab ab ab
```

There may be other words/text between the occurrences of the string "ab" which I want to replace.  It is not known how many times the string "ab" appears before "START", between "START" and "END", and after "END".  It might not appear at all.

I would prefer not to have break up each line at the START and END delimiters, do a global s/ab/cd/g on that line only, and then rejoin the lines.  Is there a regex that will only match the "ab" between the delimiters?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This regexp should do the basic... but I don't know Vim... `/START.*?(ab).*?END/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:%s/START\zs.*\zeEND/\=substitute(submatch(0), 'ab', 'cd', 'g')/
```

- `\zs` and `\ze` are zero-width and don't match anything. They simple denote the *start* and the *end* of the match.
- `\=` lets us use any expression (and therefore any function from `:h function-list`) within the `:s` command.
- `submatch(0)` contains the string we just matched.
- Then we `substitute()` all occurrences of `ab` by `cd`.

That's kind of a standard pattern that can be used in many ways.

Help:

```
:h /zero-width
:h /\zs
:h /\ze
:h sub-replace-expression
:h submatch()
:h substitute()
```

Comment: You can also use positive look-behind's (`\@<=`) & look-ahead assertions (`\@<=`) if you wan to avoid the sub-replace-expression. e.g. `:%s/\(START.*\)\@<=ab\(.*END\)\@=/cd/g`. These assertions are similar to Perl's `(?=)` & `(?=)` assertions.

Comment: To improve the readability and typing of the substitution I would recomend swiching the delimiter and using very magic, like this: `%s,\v(START.*)@<=ab(.*END)@=,cd,g`

Comment: I read this answer to my question some time ago, but neglected to express my appreciation.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Dispite beein a regular expression possibility one can use a substitution inside a visual block selection (Select the block where you want the substituition) and then:

```
:'<,'>s/\%Vab/cd/g
```

Explanation

```
'<,'> ............. refers to the visual block
s/ ................ substitution
\%V ............... that's the trick, it restricts the substitution
ab ................ old pattern
cd ................ new pattern
g  ................ globally
```

For more information see: `:h /\%V`

Comment: This is useful information! My impression had been that the V will act on the entire line, including parts of the same line before/after the visual block area, but I see now that I was mistaken.

Comment: I had neglected to give this a vote up even though I had found it useful, so I am doing so rather belatedly now.  (Sorry, I don't log in to Stack Overflow that often.)  Thanks!